# Django REST-framework: Making a field optional

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

My users can create one or more lists with items.

I'm using `django REST-framework` and subclass the 'viewsets.ModelViewSet' to receive a `json` object `list_item` which has as a `foreign key`: the list field.

Here is what I want to do:

- automatically create a new list when a user posts his very first item. At the moment this creates an error because the list id is required.
- Posting the list id should be optional (so that the users can post to more than one list)

Testcode (simplified):

```
test_posting_item_creates_list(self):
    item = {
        'name': "test",
     #   'list': 1,
        'user': self.user.id,

    }
    response = self.client.post('/api/listitems/',
                        json.dumps(item),
                        content_type="application/json")
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 201, 'statuscode is 201 created')
```

This is my serializer

```
class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    # this works for changing the list but a list field is required when posting
    def validate(self, attrs):     
        if 'list' in attrs:
             attrs['list'] = TodayList.objects.create()


    class Meta:
        model = TodayListItem
        fields =('id',
                 'name',
                 'user',
                 'list',
    )
```

With my `validate` method I can change the list, to a different one so I tried:
`if 'list' not in attrs:` but that doesnt work.

Is the Serializer the right place to "intercept" the post and create the list? How can I make a field optional?

Answer (score 2):

In your serializer you can mark your fields as not required by passing `required` arguments as `False`

```
class UserResponse(ModelSerializer):
    response = IntegerField()
    meta_data = MetaDataSerializer(allow_null=True, required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on Django REST framework manual

> **Field-level validation**
>
> You can specify custom field-level validation by adding
>   .validate_ methods to your Serializer subclass. These are
>   analogous to .clean_ methods on Django forms, but accept
>   slightly different arguments.
>
> They take a dictionary of deserialized attributes as a first argument,
>   and the field name in that dictionary as a second argument (which will
>   be either the name of the field or the value of the source argument to
>   the field, if one was provided).

So, the Solution is to create a list validation method like this:

```
def validate_list(self, attrs, source):
    """
    Check that the list is correct or not?
    """
    if list not in attrs:
        list_item = TodayList.objects.create()
        list = list_item.id
    return attrs
```

Another solution is in the model level, by overriding the `save()` and check the list id.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.list is None:
        self.list = TodayList.objects.create()
    super(TodayListItem, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
```

Comment: Your second solution works partly: I can create items without posting a list id in the json object, but I have to remove the list field from the  `ItemSerializer` so I can't set it with the post.

(I also need to use `if self.list_id is None:` in the save method of the model because it is a primary key)

Comment: What about the first one? not working? make sure you remove the validate() function first before using it. Also include the TodayList class in the file. Let me know if you need anything.